# Javascript filter data based on the ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, object

I have an object that contains these data.

```
 {id: 1864,
 courseContentId: 481,
 fileName: GymMembership.jpg
 }
 {id: 1865,
 courseContentId: 481,
 fileName: Field.jpg
 }
 {id: 1866,
 courseContentId: 482,
 fileName: Track.jpg
 }
```

And i wanted to show them seperately on the view based on the courseContentId by creating a new object and this is my desired output.

```
 {id: 1864,
 courseContentId: 481,
 fileName: GymMembership.jpg
 }
 {id: 1865,
 courseContentId: 481,
 fileName: Field.jpg
 }
```

---

```
 {id: 1866,
 courseContentId: 482,
 fileName: Track.jpg
 }
```

What kind of javascript function is suitable for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: You answered your question in the title.... [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)!

Comment: @slider Yes but in my case i need to show them seperately based on the courseContentId. It's similar to the show only unique but i need to show all with the same courseContentId seperately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `_.GroupBy`, rather than applying multiple filters.

```js
courses = [{id: 1864,
 courseContentId: 481,
 fileName: 'GymMembership.jpg'
 },
 {id: 1865,
 courseContentId: 481,
 fileName: 'Field.jpg'
 },
 {id: 1866,
 courseContentId: 482,
 fileName: 'Track.jpg'
 }]
 
var grouped = _.groupBy(courses, function(course) {
  return course.courseContentId;
});
console.log("Grouped")
console.log(grouped);
console.log("Filter by 481")
console.log(grouped["481"]);
console.log("Filter by 482")
console.log(grouped["482"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Almost but i'm not supposed to put manually the ID. What function in javascript that gets all the similar property.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, You want grouped array of similar `courseContentId`. am I right? if yes then I have updated answer for same. You can find first consoled output, otherwise let me know.

Comment: Thanks. But i have one more question. How can i keep the original index number after using group by?

Comment: @TheNinja, You can append index explicitly in array to sort the same or you can sort by "key" of grouped array. Let me what is reason behind getting same index.

Answer (score 1):

```
let yourDesiredContentId = 481;
let result = array.filter(el => el.courseContentId === yourDesiredContentId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if there's an easy way to do that. Anyway, try this:

```js
var test = [{
    id: 1864,
    courseContentId: 481,
    fileName: 'GymMembership.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 1865,
    courseContentId: 481,
    fileName: 'Field.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 1866,
    courseContentId: 482,
    fileName: 'Track.jpg'
  }
];

console.log(filter(test, 'courseContentId', 481));

function filter(arr, key, value) {
  return arr.reduce((data, item) => {
    if (item[key] == value) data.push(item);
    return data;
  }, []);
}
```